# Via Node.js convert following lines of text to array object as qualified?

Tags: node.js

I realize the title is cryptic, please for give that.  This has been driving me crazy.  How can I get the following lines into a node.js array object.  Where for each line, first parameter, becomes a key, and the index and value are abstracted as well, such the index is sub key.

Input (String split by delimiter '\n'):

```
'hdmi_force_cec_address:0': '65535'
'hdmi_force_cec_address:1': '65535'
'hdmi_force_hotplug:0': '1'
'hdmi_pixel_freq_limit:0': '0x11e1a300'
'hdmi_pixel_freq_limit:1': '0x11e1a300'
```

Desired output (i.e., Nodejs Object):

```
{
  'hdmi_force_cec_address': { '0' : '65535' }, { '1' : '65535' } },
  'hdmi_force_hotplug': { '0' : '1'},
  'hdmi_pixel_freq_limit': { '0' : '0x11e1a300' }, { '1' : '0x11e1a300' } }
}
```

The unique key, the indexed items, i.e. "X:Y" reference a scenario where X could be any number from 0 to whatever, each Y may or may not be unique per X per key.

If it is easier to just JSON-ify the input, if you will, that would be acceptable as well, versus a nodejs object structure.

Answer (score 1):

First, the desired output isn't a valid JSON, each value should be an array. like that:

```
{
  'hdmi_force_cec_address': [{ '0' : '65535' }, { '1' : '65535' }],
  'hdmi_force_hotplug': [{ '0' : '1'}],
  'hdmi_pixel_freq_limit': [{ '0' : '0x11e1a300' }, { '1' : '0x11e1a300' }]
}
```

Now for the code. You can use `replace` to clear `'` and   to get more clean values.
Then split by `:` to get your 3 values per line.
Finally, push the `key-value` into the array of the desired key in `obj`.

(Note that you need to init the array of each key if it is not created yet).

Snippet:

```js
    var lines = ["'hdmi_force_cec_address:0': '65535'",
    "'hdmi_force_cec_address:1': '65535'",
    "'hdmi_force_hotplug:0': '1'",
    "'hdmi_pixel_freq_limit:0': '0x11e1a300'",
    "'hdmi_pixel_freq_limit:1': '0x11e1a300'"];


    var obj={}
    lines.forEach((line)=>{
        let splittedLine = line.replace(/[' ]/g, '').split(':');
        obj[splittedLine[0]] ? obj[splittedLine[0]].push({[splittedLine[1]] : splittedLine[2]}) : obj[splittedLine[0]]=[{[splittedLine[1]] : splittedLine[2]}];
    });
    
    console.log(obj);
```